# MPI Error: "There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy "

Tags: mpi, cpu

When I run my MPI program on my MacPro, which has 4 CPUs,  I get the error that there are not enough slots available. This occurs only when I run above 2 cores. If I create a host file and run MPI it works for any arbitrary number of cores. I would still like to know the reason why I cannot directly run:

```
mpirun -np 3 ./myprogram
```

when I even do have 4 physical cores.

Comment: I think there are 4 physical threads, but only 2 physical cores. You can run the `lstopo` command from `hwloc` to co firm that

Comment: Neither lstopo nor hwloc can be run on my terminal ?

Comment: you can install the `hwloc` package from `brew`, and then run `lstopo`. an other option is to click the apple icon, then `About This Mac` and then `System Report ...` and check `Total Number of Cores` in the `Hardware overview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See #22-24 here: https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#slots-without-hostfiles

In brief, MPI needs to know when it's oversubscribed (running more processes than physical processors/threads available on the system) so that it knows to yield the processor more frequently